# bootstrap data-toggle collapse not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have this html test case taken almost entirely from bootstrap's examples, but when I press any of the buttons, the div is not shown.

Bootstrap 4 files are hosted locally because it's a local application not a web app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popper.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Link with href
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Button with data-target
            </button>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="card card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include `bootstrap.js` after `jquery.js`

Comment: You should probably move your scripts out of the header and to the bottom just inside the body tag